# Выделение строки в текстовом поле с форматированием

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет! Хочу узнать, как можно сделать такое выделение строки на C# (без левой боковой панели) в `RichTextBox`: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обработчик нажатия кнопки мыши по richTextBox1

```
//Получаем индекс нажатого знака
int charIndex = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
//Получаем номер строки по знаку
int lineIndex = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(charIndex);
//Получаем номер индекса, который стоит 1-м в строке
int startFromIndex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIndex);
//Получаем длину строки
int lineLength = richTextBox1.Lines[lineIndex].Length;
//Выделяем текст с первого символа строки до конца строки
richTextBox1.Select(startFromIndex, lineLength);
//Устанавливаем выделенному тексту оранжевый фон
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
//Снимаем выделение
richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
```

Comment: Цвет можно задать ещё и через RGB:  
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 191, 0)

Comment: Спасибо Всем!